# Junk File after compiling

Tags: compiling

Every time I compile software I get a lot of useless files and folders after compiling (junk files )

However I do not know what files to delete because I am afraid it might damage the software.

For example this situation 
[image]

So is there a way to automatically remove junk files after compiling or a way to safely spot junk files and remove them manually

Compiling this particular software

## Building

- Get the official 1.40 source from http://nestopia.sourceforge.net/
- Unpack it
- Unpack this overlay over it
- Go to the directory where you unpacked this and type "make".  ("make -j3" for
  dual-core, "make -j5" for quad).

Before running the emulator, copy the following files to a folder named .nestopia

Please not I have not installed this software.

Comment: What makes you think any of those files are junk?

Comment: Well I do not know about this software particular but other software I compiled I took only the binary file out and the software worked without a problem. I believe something here is extra because a NES emulator can not be 187,5 MB the windows version is 2.7 MB sooo

Comment: It really depends on the software. Every installation from source is different.

Comment: **Most** of source packages let you remove completely the source directory after you have done a successful `make install` or equivalent. But in the end, it boils down to each program, so you have to read its documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, sadly this particular software documentation does not say anything about make install, it only says to use make. so other software that I am going to compile "make install" might do the rick ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**These files are generated product of your compilation,** so they are certainly not junk but the result of your efforts compiling.

Compilation doesn't occur in the same file; `out.c` compiled code doesn't get written to `out.c` but to `out.o`, for example. When you compile something you tell the compiler (more or less):

1. read this file.
2. process and link it
3. write the output here

So, what you are seeing is perfectly normal in most (if not all) languages possible. In your case, you can copy the new files into your system directory (`sudo make install` or equivalent) and then remove the sources completely, since the original sources are not necessary anymore.

These files can be cleaned (if you want the sources pristine again) with `make clean` or equivalent.

Comment: Is there a way that I can avoid make install or "make install" because the documentation only says do **"make -j3" for
  dual-core, "make -j5" for quad**

Comment: @Levan when asking a question it's immensely helpful that you include the guide you are following

Comment: I updated the description, but This might be a bad example, I wanted to know in general how to get rid of junk files and this was  I think a bad software example that I specified